# Module can't find a module in the same folder

Tags: python, module

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project
|    baz.py
|
|____pack1
|    |
|    |   foobar.py
|    |   test1.py
|    |
|
```

Content of test1.py is:
`import foobar`

Content of baz.py is :
`from pack1 import test1`

When I run test1.py, it imports foobar without a problem.
But when I run baz.py, it throws an exception:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'`

Why is this happening and how can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `test1.py` script, it works because Python will add the script's directory automatically to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) (which contains the directories to be searched during imports):

> [...] As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. [...]

So when `import foobar` is encountered, it will successfully search the directory `project/pack1` since that is the directory which also contains the `test1.py` script.

However, when you run `baz.py`, since it resides in another directory, `project/pack1` is never added to `sys.path` and thus `foobar.py` cannot be found.

You can fix this by using the following import statement in `test1.py`:

```py
from . import foobar
```

This tells Python that the `foobar` module is located inside the same package as the importing module (i.e. `test1` in this case). Now running `python baz.py` should work.

However, when you try to run `python pack1/test1.py` now, there should be an error similar to:

```
[...]
    from . import foobar
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is because when you run `python pack1/test1.py` directly, is has no information about the package that contains the `test1` module. You can fix this by invoking the script with the [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m):

```
/path/to/project$ python -m pack1.test1
/path/to/project$ python baz.py
```

Both of the above should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, This is because `baz.py` won't get `foobar.py` module directly from `test1.py`.

---

Whenever `baz.py` reads `import foobar` inside `test1.py`, it wants to import it separately (not to be dependent on `test1.py`), that is why you get this error.
to solve it, you can type `from pack1 import foobar` inside `test1.py` , So `baz.py`
reads `from pack1 import foobar` instead of `import foobar`.